# Show the results only using DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use the datatables (jQuery plug-in) to show my data with the searching function. However , I don't want to show all the row default , I want the table only show the searching results. Can I do that?

Comment: sure you can .... need a lot more details though if you want code help

Comment: Also please include what version of datatables you are running. The API support can be drastically different depending on what version you have.

Comment: if you are running with the serverSide  set to true, you would have to write server side code to do that based on the info handed you via ajax.  If DataTables has all of the rows, the search box  built in can do all of that for you.